# Character encoding on page load

Tags: html, angular, utf-8, character-encoding

When I **reload** page in my Angular 2 app I get the following Polish character encoding problem:

```
City List / Dup%C3%B3w
```

But when I transition from another state everything is fine:

```
City List / Dupów
```

I included this in a head of my intex.html.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

How to solve this issue?

@edit

I get `Dupów` from URI as a stateParam and after digging in the code it seems that the param is not decoded after being retrieved.

Comment: May you please add details on how are you providing this data and how are you binding?

Comment: The official name is not "character encoding problem", it is "URL-encoded string". I'm sure that Angular will not handle as URL something that is not a URL without a good reason (i.e., something you're doing wrong in your code).

Answer (score 0):

This is valid UTF-8 but your text is URL encoded.
You can use the decodeURIComponent function or check if encodeURIComponent (in JS, urldecode for PHP) is used somewhere.

```
decodeURIComponent('City List / Dup%C3%B3w');
```

> => "City List / Dupów"